# Random password generator in C

Tags: c, random, generator

This is a simple password generator. What do you think about it? I am learning C for a while at school and at home. This just has a mix of symbols, lowercase, uppercase and numbers, with a configurable length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int randomizer = 0;
    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));
    char numbers [] = "1234567890";
    char letter [] = "abcdefghijklmnoqprstuvwyzx";
    char letterr [] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQPRSTUYWVZX";
    char symbols [] = "!@#$%^&*(){}[]:<>?,./";
    printf("\nHow long password:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char password[n];
    randomizer = rand() % 4;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(randomizer == 1)
        {
            password[i] = numbers[rand() % 10];
            randomizer = rand() % 4;
            printf("%c", password[i]);
        }
        else if (randomizer == 2)
        {
            password[i] = symbols[rand() % 26];
            randomizer = rand() % 4;
            printf("%c", password[i]);
        }
        else if (randomizer == 3)
        {
            password[i] = letterr[rand() % 26];
            randomizer = rand() % 4;
            printf("%c", password[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            password[i] = letter[rand() % 21];
            randomizer = rand() % 4;
            printf("%c", password[i]);
        }
    }
    return main();
}
```

Comment: This is a very small subset of Unicode passwords.

Comment: Don’t actually use passwords generated with this for anything, by the way – beyond the bias Edward mentioned, `rand()` is weak, predictable, and reversible on most platforms.

Comment: You should treat all characters equally, otherwise you reduce the randomness of the distribution. With your current approach, a given numeric character is more than twice as likely as any non-numeric character P("1") = 1/4 * 1/10 = 1/40, P("A") = 1/4 * 1/26 = 1/104

Comment: Variable name `letterr` for capital letters seems lazy

Comment: This assignment doesn't require that something from each group be used, so why even have groups?  I.e. use `"1234567890abc…xyzABC…XYZ!@#$%^&*(){}[]:<>?,./"`, and most of the other code will collapse into one small loop. — Or better yet, assuming ASCII, just pick a random integer between 33 and 126 and use that as the character and you don't even need a list of characters.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I see some things that I think could help you improve your code.

### Decompose your program into functions

All of the logic here is in `main` in one rather long and dense chunk of code.  It would be better to decompose this into separate functions.

### Check return values for errors

The call to `scanf` can fail.  You must check the return values to make sure they haven't or your program may crash (or worse) when given malformed input or due to low system resources.  Rigorous error handling is the difference between mostly working versus bug-free software.  You should strive for the latter.

### Use more whitespace to enhance readability of the code

Instead of crowding things together like this:

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
```

most people find it more easily readable if you use more space:

```
for (i=0; i < n; i++)
```

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

Instead of hard-coding the constants 26 and 4 in the code, it would be better to use a `#define` or `const` and name them.

### Avoid `scanf` if you can

There are so many [well known problems with `scanf`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf) that you're usually better off avoiding it.

### Don't recursively call `main`

The `main()` function can be called recursively in C, but it's a bad idea.  You could blow up your stack and there's really no good reason to do that here.  Just use a loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238179/calling-main-in-main-in-c for details.

### Use a better random number generator

You are currently using

```
password[i] = numbers[rand() % 10];
```

There are a number of problems with this approach. This will generate lower numbers more often than higher ones -- it's not a uniform distribution.  Another problem is that the low order bits of the random number generator are not particularly random, so neither is the result.  On my machine, there's a slight but measurable bias toward 0 with that.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999075/generate-a-random-number-within-range/2999130#2999130) for details, but I'd recommend changing that to the `rand_lim` in that link and also duplicated below.

### Results

Here's an alternative that uses all of these ideas.  It also gets a length from the command line so there's no need for a prompt or `scanf`.  It eliminates the need for counting characters and uses the better random number generator mentioned above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int rand_lim(int limit) {
/* return a random number between 0 and limit inclusive.
 */

    int divisor = RAND_MAX/(limit+1);
    int retval;

    do { 
        retval = rand() / divisor;
    } while (retval > limit);

    return retval;
}

char picker(const char *charset) {
    return charset[rand_lim(strlen(charset)-1)];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        puts("Usage: pwgen len");
        return 1;
    }
    int len = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (len <= 0) {
       puts("Length must be a positive non-zero integer"); 
       return 2;
    }
    const char* groups[] = {
        "1234567890",  // numbers
        "abcdefghijklmnoqprstuvwyzx",  // lowercase
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQPRSTUYWVZX",  // uppercase
        "!@#$%^&*(){}[]:<>?,./",    // symbols
    };
    const size_t numGroups = sizeof(groups)/sizeof(groups[0]);
    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));

    // only proceed if we got a number
    for ( ; len; --len) {
        unsigned group = rand_lim(numGroups-1);
        putchar(picker(groups[group]));
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: I like most of your suggestions.  But I think the biggest problem in OP's sample is use of a poor random generator to make a "random" password.  I take issue with the *Use a better random number generator* section recommend to replace `rand()` with `rand() / 10`.  Point to `getrandom()` or `RtlGenRandom()` or even `/dev/urandom`.  The treatment of uniformity in your code sample is a good consideration.  On some platforms, you can use the `arc4random_uniform()` function to generate numbers in uniform range without rolling your own.  (Unfortunately, it's not in Linux libc.)

Comment: @ConradMeyer: I chose to approach the problem with portability in mind, hence `rand_lim` uses only standard library functions.  As for the larger problem, I'd go further and say that this entire password generation approach [is deeply flawed](https://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: The C standard doesn't require implementations to provide a real random number generator, but any real implementation that you'd be writing a program like this for does.  Portability is generally a good aspiration, but doesn't mean we should be providing dangerous examples of "corrected" password generator code that uses non-random inputs.  People really do copy/paste code off of stackoverflow, and those people are the same ones who are going to think `rand`/`random` are random.  Anyway, that's just my opinion. :-)

Comment: Did you intend "don't use `scanf` because it's unreliable, better use `atoi`" to be a joke, or was it an accident?

Answer (score 14):

There is a bug in this line:

```
password[i] = symbols[rand() % 26];
```

`symbols` is only 21 characters long, so this line triggers undefined behavior when `rand() % 26` is greater than 21 (and when `rand() % 26` is exactly 21, it puts a null byte in the password). You meant for this 26 to go with `letter` instead, and for the 21 to go with `symbols`.

This would be less likely to happen if you avoid using "magic" numbers. The error is harder to make (or at least, easier to spot) if you write this instead:

```
password[i] = symbols[rand() % (sizeof symbols - 1)]
```

Of course, you can also `#define` a macro (as Edward's answer also suggests), but I would still define it using `sizeof`:

```
#define NUM_SYMBOLS (sizeof symbols - 1)
```

Using `sizeof` to calculate the size, rather than using a literal value like `26`, ensures that you will not forget to update the count if the size of the array changes.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if this is just an exercise to learn about working with strings and numbers, or if you ever intend to use this to generate real passwords. But if you do, this line can be a serious problem:

```
srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));
```

Since you are using the current time, in seconds, to seed the pseudo-random number generator, you have severly limited the number of possible passwords. If I know which day you ran this program to generate a password, there are only 86400 possible passwords I need to test. That's an entropy of 16 bits. If I can guess the hour, you are down to 12 bits. And if I know the exact time, perhaps because your mail with encrypted text has it in the headers, I *know* your password.

(`RAND_MAX` is only guaranteed by the standard to be at least 32767, which would correspond to 15 bits of entropy, but on my machine it is 2147483647, which is 31 bits of entropy.)

Comment: I agree!  I think this is the biggest problem.  `rand()` looks like a random number interface, but it very much isn't.  It's not even a good fast simulation generator.  Be careful not to confuse the *range* of `rand()` with *entropy*, though.  Your `rand` has a 31-bit range but 0 bits of entropy.  OP would be well served to learn about `getrandom()` or `getentropy()` if supported by their development platform, or simply opening `/dev/urandom` if not.  (Or pick any of the secure CSPRNG APIs on Windows 10+ — they're all backed by the same, good algorithm.)

Comment: `RAND_MAX` is independent of the entropy of the random number generator. Just adding `srand_bytes(const char *, size_t)` to the API could improve the entropy without touching `RAND_MAX`. This means your argument is flawed. `RAND_MAX` only describes the entropy of a single call to `rand()`, and for that, an entropy of 15 bits is enough.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Yes, I agree that RAND_MAX isn't really relevant to the entropy of the generated passwords.

Answer (score 7):

Take this line from every branch and put it at the end of the loop:

> ```
> printf("%c", password[i]);
> ```

Take this from every branch and put it at the start of the loop (and delete it from before the loop):

> ```
> randomizer = rand() % 4;
> ```

As Schwern observes, you can also turn the `if` chain into a `switch`/`case`, which is a bit faster and easier to read.

This makes the loop look like:

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    randomizer = rand() % 4;
    switch (randomizer) {
    case 1:
        password[i] = numbers[rand() % 10];
        break;
    case 2:
        password[i] = symbols[rand() % 26];
        break;
    case 3:
        password[i] = letterr[rand() % 26];
        break;
    default:
        password[i] = letter[rand() % 21];
        break;
    }
    printf("%c", password[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why stop? `struct { char *const str; size_t n; } table[] = { { numbers, sizeof numbers - 1 }, { symbols, sizeof symbols - 1 }, ... }, *t; for(i = 0; i < n; i++) t = table + rand() % (sizeof table / sizeof *table), password[i] = t->str(rand() % t->n);`

Answer (score 6):

This is a good start!
You do have a couple of bugs though.  Firstly, these two lines:

```
        password[i] = symbols[rand() % 26];
```

and

```
        password[i] = letter[rand() % 21];
```

seem to have their numbers mixed up - swap the `21` and `26` here.

Secondly, this line is bad practice.  It may work, but is not the 'right' way to do this.  My coding teacher would have had a hissy-fit if they'd seen this!

```
char password[n];
```

I was taught that variable declarations should pretty much always be right at the top of a function.  The 'right' way to deal with this is to simply declare a char pointer, and then use `malloc` to allocate the correct amount of memory to the string when you know it's size, and don't forget to free the memory when it's no longer being used.

```
char *password = NULL;

printf("\nHow long password:");
scanf("%d", &n);

password = (char *)malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char));  /* String length +1 for NULL terminator */

...

free(password);
```

Thirdly, sanitize your inputs - always assume your end user is the world's biggest idiot, and when asked to enter `How long password:`, may just enter `twelve` as their answer, or even just `cabbage`.  A simple loop can do this, and a minor change to your prompt can help reduce invalid answers that crash your program:

```
    do
    {
      printf("\nHow long password (8-32):");
      scanf("%d", &n);
    } while ((n < 8) || (n > 32));
```

Fourthly, I would personally use `switch`/`case` rather than `if`/`else` `if`/`else`, but that is just a personal preference in this case.

Finally, I can only agree with everything in Edward's response.

Here is your code with the changes I'd make:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ALPHA_SIZE 26
#define NUM_SIZE   10
#define SYM_SIZE   21

void main()
{
    int i, n;
    char *password = NULL;

    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));

    do
    {
      printf("\nHow long password (8-32):");
      scanf("%d", &n);
    } while ((n < 8) || (n > 32));

    password = (char *)malloc((n + 1) * (sizeof(char)));
    printf("%s", makePassword(password, n));

    free(password);
}

char *makePassword(char *pwd, int pwd_length)
{
    int i, randomizer;
    char numbers[] = "1234567890";
    char letter[]  = "abcdefghijklmnoqprstuvwyzx";
    char letterr[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQPRSTUYWVZX";
    char symbols[] = "!@#$%^&*(){}[]:<>?,./";

    for (i=0; i<pwd_length; i++)
    {
        randomizer = rand() % 4;

        switch(randomizer)
        {
            case 0: pwd[i] = getPwdChar(numbers, NUM_SIZE);
            break;

            case 1: pwd[i] = getPwdChar(letter, ALPHA_SIZE);
            break;

            case 2: pwd[i] = getPwdChar(letterr, ALPHA_SIZE);
            break;

            case 3: pwd[i] = getPwdChar(symbols, SYM_SIZE);
            break;

            default: break;
        }
    }
    password[pwd_length] = NULL;

    return (pwd);
}

char getPwdChar(char *charlist, int len) 
{
  return (charlist[(rand() / (RAND_MAX / len))]);
}
```

Comment: *I was taught that variable declarations should pretty much always be right at the top of a function.* I disagree; variables should not be declared until they are initialized, and in the smallest possible scope, to avoid accidentally "leaking" values from commonly used variable names like `i` and `n`, and to increase the chance you will get a compiler error or warning if you make a mistake. "Always put your variables at the top of a function" is a holdover from C89 when all variables *had* to be declared at the top of a function. Today, it's bad advice.

Comment: Also, while I would also use `malloc` here, it's not *more correct* than using a VLA (variable-length array). Your teacher may have had a fit but that's just their opinion, not gospel truth. What *is* gospel truth is that `void main()` is non-standard.

Comment: @StefanCole "I was taught that variable declarations should pretty much always be right at the top of a function." The days of C89 are long past us.

Comment: `rand() % 21` I think this causes a modulo bias, because RAND_MAX isn't perfectly divisible by 21.

Comment: C89 requires variables to be defined at beginning of scope blocks, which is wider than just the start of functions.

Comment: `void main` should be `int main`.

Comment: `rand()` is an unfortunately named legacy C API.  I'd suggest using one of the interfaces designed to generate numbers for secrets like passwords: `getrandom()` on Unix (or `getentropy()` on OpenBSD), `RtlGenRandom()` on Windows.  That said, @Alexander-ReinstateMonica's point about bias is still a factor and Edward's answer shows a construction to correctly avoid it.  If you're on a BSD platform, there is also the libc `arc4random_uniform()`, which generates a (good) random number with uniform probability in some range up to `UINT32_MAX - 1`.

Comment: *may just enter 'twelve' as their answer, or even just 'cabbage'.* or may enter `Ctrl+D` and send EOF as an input. I've seen some programs to crash in a funny way when treated like this. I'm not sure your loop would work properly when treated this way.

Comment: Many more compilers support C89 than C99. It depends what one is doing. _Eg_, [MSVC conformance with C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#C) and [Does MSVC2017 fully support C99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48615184/does-visual-studio-2017-fully-support-c99).

Comment: @Neil MSVC is a C++ compiler. C++ also allows declaring variables anywhere in the code, although it does not have VLAs. Anyway, the OP is clearly using C99 (or later), so I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @trentcl my point is . . . what was my point? . . . just because it's old, doesn't mean it's not relevant; especially when the suggestion is fundamentally different wrt allocation. However, you have a point, this is C99 code, and passwords generally have a practical length limit.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't initialize dynamic character arrays with a character string.  I.e. don't, for an (implicitly) auto variable, write:

   ```
   char numbers [] = "1234567890";
   ```

   As written, the array is copied from a constant to an automatic variable at run time.
   Instead write:

   ```
   char *numbers = "1234567890";
   ```

   Or better still:

   ```
   char const *const numbers = "1234567890";
   ```

   Alternatively, move it outside the function to make it global, or declare it static (in which case the array is initialized at compile and load time).  Thus, it is also reasonable to write something like:

   ```
   static char const numbers[] = "1234567890";
   ```
2. Don't use `rand()` and `srand()`.  They really are just to old and decrepit.  At the very least, use `rand48()` and `srand48()`.  Better still, find a cryptographic grade random number generator and use that.   This goes along with a previously mentioned "don't use `scanf()`".  (There are a few other functions you shouldn't touch, like `gets()`.)
3. If you try to develop this more fully, you may start getting extra restrictions, like don't use both "0" and "O", or both "1" and "l".  These two are about eliminating confusing characters.  Another might be to change the symbol set, as many sites use restricted symbol sets.   (And I note you already eliminated ", ', `, and ; yourself.)  Thus, I suggest dynamically building a single list of acceptable characters, and using a dynamic length for said list.
4. Personally, I've always like generating passwords by generating cryptographic-grade random characters (i.e. 8 bit samples) and then discarding unacceptable (unprintable) characters.  I'm sure there are reasons why this isn't good.

Comment: Why not `static const char numbers[] = "1234567890";` inside the function?

Comment: @Martin: That is fine either inside or outside the function.  The point was to have it compile/load time initialized instead of run time initialized.  I did say "make it global, or declare it static".  One can of course do both, though the sematics of static at the global scope are different.

Comment: 4) is perfectly fine as long as you simply remove the unprintable characters and then repeat until you've got a long enough string. This is one of the standard ways how to get unbiased modulo N random numbers. The JDK does it this way (loop until you get a number smaller than the largest number that cannot be mapped unbiased into the different buckets).

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding any of the non-cryptographic unseeded libc PRNGs, including `rand48`.  Just skip directly to `getrandom()`, or if you're on an older platform, `/dev/urandom`, or on Windows (especially 10+), there are good CSPRNG APIs available there that I don't memorize the names for :-).

Answer (score 2):

Previous commenters have alluded to the fact that the rand() function provided by programming language libraries is at best pseudorandom and incapable of providing secure passwords. It would be reasonable to use the /dev/random device (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) on unix-like systems, or the Microsoft library CryptGenRandom on Windows systems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom -- lighter-weight alternative here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/michael_howard/2005/01/14/cryptographically-secure-random-number-on-windows-without-using-cryptoapi/) as sources of randomness, as these use observed external events (e.g., from device drivers) to generate a random number pool rather than using a pseudorandom generator whose outputs can be predicted.

Comment: Hi Eric!  I totally agree that use of `rand` is concerning here and agree with your suggested replacements.  One language quibble, though: `rand` isn't "at best pseuodrandom."  It's explicitly required to be a deterministic sequence generator by the C standard.

Comment: Good point. My comment "at best pseudorandom" referred to the real concern that the rand() implementation could itself be defective. Don't laugh! -- some nice examples are given [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs161/fa08/Notes/random.pdf).

Comment: Ah, sure.  "Nine, nine, nine, nine..."

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to the already mentioned recursively main logic.

If you run the program logic to often with that you can generate a stack overflow and run out of memory.

You can use a forever loop instead:

```
int main()
{
    for(;;) {
    // youre code here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another advantage of changing to `for(;;)` not mentioned yet:
This way you can also refactor some stuff out before the `for(;;)` like the constants.

Comment: It's a good point, but I did actually mention that in my answer.

Comment: you are right I over read it.